# How to create a Dialog fragment for Sherlock fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-alertdialog

In my app I'm using ActionBArSherlock to create fragments. The main activity is a *SherlockFragmentActivity* from where I create the fragments. The fragments are in their own class files and they extend *SherlockFragment*. I need to display an alert dialog in a fragment but I'm unable to do so.

I googled it, but in vain. I checked the samples given along with the ActionBarSherlock library. They have shown how to create a dialog in a FragmentActivity but not in a Fragment. I tried implementing the same in a fragment but I can't use `getSupportFragmentManager()`. It is undefined for the type Fragment.

```
public class Fragment1 extends SherlockFragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false);
                    return rootView;
}

public void someFunction(){
    if(somethingHappens)
        showDialog();
}

  //the code that follows is from the sample in ActionBarSherlock

void showDialog() {
    DialogFragment newFragment = MyAlertDialogFragment.newInstance(
            R.string.alert_dialog_two_buttons_title);
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog"); //getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type Fragment
}

public void doPositiveClick() {
    // Do stuff here.
    Log.i("FragmentAlertDialog", "Positive click!");
}

public void doNegativeClick() {
    // Do stuff here.
    Log.i("FragmentAlertDialog", "Negative click!");
}


public static class MyAlertDialogFragment extends SherlockDialogFragment {

    public static MyAlertDialogFragment newInstance(int title) {
        MyAlertDialogFragment frag = new MyAlertDialogFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("title", title);
        frag.setArguments(args);
        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        int title = getArguments().getInt("title");

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setIcon(R.drawable.alert_dialog_icon)
                .setTitle(title)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_dialog_ok,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            ((FragmentAlertDialogSupport)getActivity()).doPositiveClick(); // Cannot cast from FragmentActivity to fragment
                        }
                    }
                )
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.alert_dialog_cancel,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            ((FragmentAlertDialogSupport)getActivity()).doNegativeClick(); //Cannot cast from FragmentActivity to fragment
                        }
                    }
                )
                .create();
    }
}
```

Can you tell me how to show a dialog in a Sherlock Fragment?

Comment: use `getFragmentManager` inside the fragment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From within a SherlockFragment you may call

```
getSherlockActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
```

to get your fragment manager to show the dialog fragment.

Comment: Wow! What about when calling onPositiveClick and onNegativeClick in onCreateDialog?

Comment: Also I have used getActivity().getAssets() to get assets, should I be using getSherlockActivty().getAssets()?

Comment: Ah ok. What you can do is set the target fragment of MyAlertDialogFragment to be your Fragment1. Ex. newFragment.setTargetFragment(this); when creating the dialog fragment. Then in your pos/neg clicks you can retrieve it using ((Fragment1)getTargetFragment()).doNegativeClick();

Comment: And getting the assets like that is fine. The Sherlock method to get assets likely defaults to the standard activity call for getting them anyways.

Comment: it's crashing for `((Fragment1)getTargetFragment()).doNegativeClick()`

Comment: Odd the crash. As long as you set the target fragment before calling show(..) there should be no issues with that. Glad you figured it out, though.